# ideal rest in between sets for increasing bodyweight exercises

Tags: weightlifting, push-ups, pull-ups, bodyweight-exercises, muscle-endurance

So I want to increase the number of pull-ups, push-ups, sit-ups I can do.

I've been leaving an arbitrary 2 minutes in between sets. Is this the ideal amount of time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two minutes is fine. More rest means you'll improve your muscular endurance and recovery time less, however your strength will improve more.

People training for strength should take 3 to 5 minute breaks, or even more in some circumstances. People training for fitness, hypertrophy, or endurance might want to work shorter rests--2 minutes, 1 minute, or even circuit training, where one does another exercise (e.g. jump rope or air squats) instead of resting.